# Mysql SUM price from TWO tables

Tags: mysql

I want to query SQL from two tables `posts` and `postmeta`. each post in `posts` table has an unique ID, and in `postmeta` table there are some meta keys and values related to that post ID.

Here is an example of `posts` table

[image]

Here is the example of `postmeta` table.

[image]

I want to calculate SUM of price value in `postmeta` table per date in a given date range. That was okay, but problem is i want to SUM price by package_type='subscription' and package_type="token".(note that there are 2 package types : subscription, token)

I can't do it anyway

here is what i have tried

```
    "SELECT
        DATE(posts.post_date) date,
        SUM(postmeta.meta_value) as totalrev
    FROM postmeta 
        LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.ID = postmeta.post_id AND postmeta.meta_key = 'price'  
    WHERE 
        posts.post_author = ". $author_id ."
        AND (posts.post_date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date')
    GROUP BY
        DATE(posts.post_date) 
    "
```

Comment:  [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  DATE(p.post_date) date,
  pkg.meta_value AS package_type
  SUM(price.meta_value) AS totalrev
FROM posts AS p
INNER JOIN postmeta AS pkg 
  ON p.ID = pkg.post_id AND pkg.meta_key = 'package_type'
LEFT JOIN postmeta AS price
  ON p.ID = price.post_id AND price.meta_key = 'price'  
WHERE 
  p.post_author = ?
  AND (p.post_date BETWEEN ? AND ?)
  AND pkg.meta_value IN ('subscription', 'token')
GROUP BY
  DATE(p.post_date), package_type;
```

P.S.: Please get into the habit of using query parameters instead of concatenating or interpolating variables into your queries. It's easier to write the code, and safer with respect to SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks, its a great approach. I tried it but returning blank array. Is there any bracket missing in JOIN?

Comment: If the query executes without returning a syntax error, then the syntax is correct. If the query returns an empty result set, then there is no data in your database matching the conditions.

Comment: If i run it on DB SQL command it gives this error https://prnt.sc/4O9G1rtCRHFX

Comment: Indeed, it's a syntax error. What do you think the problem is? You should be able to diagnose it easily.

Comment: Yes, there was an error in 3rd line, a comma. lol :p